# Remove Double Quotes from Array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to remove the double quotes from a series of words in a array

"First" ; "Second", "Third"

I've produced a fiddle here which has the quotes surrounding each word

http://jsfiddle.net/e7v3fd6r/2/

Objective the Double Quotes should only surround the whole three word phrase

e.g  "First, Second ,Third"

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="giftText[0]" ng-pattern="/^\S{0,50}$/" 
               required  ng-pattern="/[a-zA-Z0-9^ ]/"<br />
        <input type="text" ng-model="giftText[1]" ng-pattern="/^\S{0,50}$/" 
               required ng-pattern="/[a-zA-Z0-9^ ]/"<br />
        <input type="text" ng-model="giftText[2]" ng-pattern="/^\S{0,50}$/" 
               required  ng-pattern="/[a-zA-Z0-9^ ]/"<br />
        <br/>Result: {{giftText}}

    </div>
</div>
```

```
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
  myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.myString = '';
      $scope.giftText = $scope.myString.split(/[ ]+/);
      console.log($scope.giftText);
```

Comment: There can not be two `ng-pattern` directives on one element.

Answer (score 1):

If it is just to display:

```
Result: "{{giftText.join(",")}}"
```

If you want to hold it in a variable then, watch input in each field, join in controller side and hold the result in any variable.

Comment: I was knowing, you just need to display :)  Good Luck :)

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.myString = '';
  $scope.giftText = $scope.myString.split(/[ ]+/);
 
  $scope.test = function(obj){
  var quotedAndCommaSeparated = '"' + obj.join(",") + '"';
  alert(quotedAndCommaSeparated);
  }
  
  console.log($scope.giftText)
 
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="giftText[0]" ng-pattern="/^\S{0,50}$/" required  ng-pattern="/[a-zA-Z0-9^ ]/"<br />
    <input type="text" ng-model="giftText[1]" ng-pattern="/^\S{0,50}$/" required ng-pattern="/[a-zA-Z0-9^ ]/"<br />
    <input type="text" ng-model="giftText[2]" ng-pattern="/^\S{0,50}$/" required  ng-pattern="/[a-zA-Z0-9^ ]/"<br />
    <button type="button" ng-click="test(giftText)">Submit</button>
    <br/>Result: {{giftText}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There can not be two `ng-pattern` directives on one element.

Comment: Thanks   but how will the test function be applied to  ng-submit="add3Words(collection, giftText)"